# Events for admin user login/logut in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, event-observer

Is there any events for admin user login and logout in magento?

I found some events for customer login but not for Admin user login

```
<events>
         <customer_login>
           <observers>
              <scommerce_customer_login><!--User Defined Unique Name-->
                 <class>scommerce_login/observer</class>
                 <method>checkLoginStatus</method>             
              </scommerce_customer_login>
           </observers>
         </customer_login>
      </events>
```

For how to get the admin users login events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <adminhtml>
<events>
            <admin_session_user_login_success>
                <observers>
                    <Ss_Supportticket_model_observer>
                        <!-- The model to be instantiated -->
                        <class>Ss_Supportticket_model_observer</class>
                        <!-- The method of the class to be called -->
                        <method>saveUserLoginSession</method>
                        <!-- The type of class to instantiate -->
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </Ss_Supportticket_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </admin_session_user_login_success>
            <!-- <controller_action_predispatch> -->
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_logout>
                <observers>
                    <Ss_Supportticket_model_observer>
                        <!-- The model to be instantiated -->
                        <class>Ss_Supportticket_model_observer</class>
                        <!-- The method of the class to be called -->
                        <method>saveUserLogoutSession</method>
                        <!-- The type of class to instantiate -->
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </Ss_Supportticket_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_index_logout>
            <!-- </controller_action_predispatch> -->
        </events>
 </adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 6):

### Login:

There are one event exit in magento which fire whenever admin user successfully logged in  and can get  user details from  it  parameter:

**event name:** `admin_session_user_login_success`

See at  class: **Mage_Admin_Model_Session**

```
  Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success', array('user' => $user));
```

Getting loggin user details: `$observer->getEvent()->getUser();`

Also fire event `admin_session_user_login_failed` when admin user goes  to fail to login

```
   Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_failed',
        array('user_name' => $username, 'exception' => $e));
```

### Logout:

For Logout cannot find any event. In this  can use controller  predispatch  & Post dispatch event .

As magento  doing  logout from  **Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController**  at logoutAction then  use any  one of below events

- `controller_action_postdispatch_admin_index_logout`
- `controller_postdispatch_admin_index_logout`

Event:  `controller_postdispatch_admin_index_logout` is better for this case.

Comment: Is there any events for admin logout/session expires in magento?

Comment: Use `controller_postdispatch_admin_index_logout`. For session timeout there is no event because no code gets executed when a user session times out.

Comment: yes..  On logout Action magento just clear current adminhtml session varible

Comment: http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/track-admin-login-records-80679.html May be this link will help some one

Comment: On your link a new event has been define at controller.And by using this your get data

Comment: Here's the archive.org version of @Naveenbos link https://web.archive.org/web/20160811105317/http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/track-admin-login-records-80679.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition if you need an event before the admin login (for example to restrict login even with a correct credentials) - you can use this

- admin_user_authenticate_before

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code resurrected from [this dead link (archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160811105317/http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/track-admin-login-records-80679.html) (untested):

```
<frontend>
   <events>
<!-- Add Observers for customer on frontend
      customer_login
      customer_logout
 -->
      <customer_login>
          <observers>
             <xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>xxx_Various_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>Observecustomerlogin</method>
             </xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
         </observers>
      </customer_login>
      <customer_logout>
          <observers>
             <xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>xxx_Various_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>Observecustomerlogout</method>
             </xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
         </observers>
      </customer_logout>
  </events>
</frontend>
      
<adminhtml>
   <events>
<!-- Add Observers for Admin on admin backend
      admin_session_user_login_success
      admin_session_user_logout
      admin_session_user_login_failed
 -->
      <admin_session_user_login_success>
          <observers>
             <xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>xxx_Various_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>Observeadminlogin</method>
             </xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
         </observers>
      </admin_session_user_login_success>
      <admin_session_user_logout>
          <observers>
             <xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>xxx_Various_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>Observeadminlogout</method>
             </xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
         </observers>
      </admin_session_user_logout>
      <admin_session_user_login_failed>
          <observers>
             <xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>xxx_Various_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>Observeadminloginfailed</method>
             </xxx_Various_Model_Observer>
         </observers>
      </admin_session_user_login_failed> 
  </events>
</adminhtml>
```